# Calculate sum of series ‎$‎\sum_{n=1}^\infty ‎\frac{x+a}{n(x+a) + n^2}‎$.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, special-functions

‎I've been stuck with calculating the sum of series of the following problem. Can you help me?‎

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty ‎\frac{x+a}{n(x+a) + n^2}‎$$

‎
for real ‎numbers ‎‎$‎a\geq 0‎$ ‎and ‎‎$‎x\geq 1‎$‎.
‎

Comment: If $x+a$ is an integer, $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{x+a}{n(x+a)+n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1n-\frac1{n+(x+a)}$ is a telescopic series.

Comment: Mathematica 12.0 answers it by Sum[(x + a)/(n*(x + a) + n^2), {n, 1, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> x + a > 0] as $\psi ^{(0)}(a+x+1)+\gamma $.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After @URL's comment, using
$$S_p=\sum_{n=1}^p\frac{x+a}{n(x+a)+n^2}=\sum_{n=1}^p\frac1n-\sum_{n=1}^p\frac1{n+(x+a)}$$ and using generalized harmonic numbers, we have
$$S_p=H_{a+x}+H_p-H_{a+x+p}$$
Now, using the asymptotics
$$H_q=\gamma +\log \left({q}\right)+\frac{1}{2 q}-\frac{1}{12
   q^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{q^3}\right)$$ and using it for the second an third term, we end with
$$S_p=H_{a+x}-\frac{a+x}{p}+O\left(\frac{1}{p^2}\right)$$